# Bold text using package MaTeX

Tags: packages, latex, fonts

Using the [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) package from our colleague [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) I had a certain problem.
I would like to highlight the result for bold, but I did not get a result that I liked.
I tried several options that I found: `\boldmath`, `\bm`, `\mathbf` and `\textbf`.
What came closest was `\mathbf`, but Pi did not get bold. Is that so?

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
MaTeX["\\int_0^r 2\\pi r\\,dr = 2\\pi \\int_0^r r\\,dr = \
2\\pi\\bigg\vert_0^r \\frac{r^2}{2} = \\bigg(2\\pi \
\\frac{r^2}{2}\\bigg)-\\bigg(2\\pi \\frac{0^2}{2}\\bigg) = \
\\frac{2\\pi r^2}{2} = \\mathbf{\\pi r^2}"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\boldsymbol{\pi}`, which renders as $\boldsymbol{\pi}$, instead of `\mathbf{\pi}`, which renders as $\mathbf{\pi}$

(don't have LaTeX on my system, so I can't test with MaTeX)

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
MaTeX["\\int_0^r 2\\pi r\\,dr = 2\\pi \\int_0^r r\\,dr = \
2\\pi\\bigg\vert_0^r \\frac{r^2}{2} = \\bigg(2\\pi \
\\frac{r^2}{2}\\bigg)-\\bigg(2\\pi \\frac{0^2}{2}\\bigg) = \
\\frac{2\\pi r^2}{2} = \\ boldsymbol{\\pi r^2}"]
```

[image]

Comment: answer found here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595/how-can-i-get-bold-math-symbols

Comment: I also get using `\pmb`

Comment: If you can help me with this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149772/is-the-beginalign-function-available-for-the-matex-package) too ...

Answer (score 3):

@JasonB already posted a good answer. I just wanted to point out two more things:

- This is a LaTeX question really, and not specific to MaTeX/Mathematica.  I suggest http://tex.stackexchange.com/ for similar future questions. The main thing to know about MaTeX is that it interprets all TeX commands in inline math mode.  I.e. when people on TeX.SE ask you to provide a complete minimal example, you simply need to put whatever you passed to MaTeX between a pair of `$...$` and put that into a minimal LaTeX document.  If you want to see the exact LaTeX document that MaTeX creates behind the scenes, then first run `ClearMaTeXCache[]`, then pass the option `"TeXFileFunction" -> Print` to the `MaTeX` function.
- `\bm` does work, but you must load the `bm` package:

  ```
  MaTeX["\\bm{\\pi}\\pi", "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{bm}"}, Magnification -> 3]
  ```

  [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks again for your attention