# Is the \begin{align} function available for the MaTeX package?

Tags: packages, latex, alignment

I would like to know if the [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) package from our colleague [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) can align the calculation steps as possible by the code below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

%% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
V &= \int_0^H dV\\
  &= \int_0^H A'\,dh\\
  &= \int_0^H \frac{Ah^2}{H^2}\,dh\\
  &= \frac{A}{H^2}\left|\frac{h^3}{3}\right|_0^H\\
  &= \frac{A}{H^2}\cdot\frac{H^3}{3}\\
  &= \frac{1}{3}AH
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
V=\frac{A}{H^2}\left[\frac{h^3}{3}\right]_0^H
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Information:** The above code is not for Mathematica software, but it is a reference for LaTeX language users.

The code below (this one yes) is what I would like to align in Mathematica software:

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
MaTeX["\\int_0^r 2\\pi r\\,dr = 2\\pi \\int_0^r r\\,dr = \
2\\pi\\bigg\vert_0^r \\frac{r^2}{2} = \\bigg(2\\pi \
\\frac{r^2}{2}\\bigg)-\\bigg(2\\pi \\frac{0^2}{2}\\bigg) = \
\\frac{2\\pi r^2}{2} = \\ boldsymbol{\\pi r^2}"]
```

**Is the `\begin{align}` function available in this package?**

Comment: This is discussed both on the webpage you linked to and the builtin documentation.  MaTeX interprets commands in inline mode, so `align` cannot be used. But `aligned` can, as @Nasser said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `aligned` from amsmath (I do not think `align` or `align*` works in Matex)

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
SetOptions[MaTeX,"Preamble"->{"\\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,latexsym,amsfonts,amsthm}"}]
```

Then

```
MaTeX["
\\begin{aligned}
V&= \\int_0^H dV\\\\
&= \\int_0^H A'\\,dh\\\\
&= \\int_0^H\\frac{Ah^2}{H^2}\\,dh\\\\
&= \\frac{A}{H^2}\\left|\\frac{h^3}{3}\\right|_0^H\\\\
&= \\frac{A}{H^2}\\cdot\\frac{H^3}{3}\\\\
&= \\frac{1}{3}AH
\\end{aligned}
"]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Second example

```
MaTeX["
\\begin{aligned}
\\int_0^r 2\\pi r\\,dr &= 2\\pi \\int_0^r r\\,dr \\\\
&= 2\\pi\\bigg\\vert_0^r \\frac{r^2}{2} \\\\
&= \\bigg(2\\pi \\frac{r^2}{2}\\bigg)-\\bigg(2\\pi \\frac{0^2}{2}\\bigg) \\\\
&= \\frac{2\\pi r^2}{2} \\\\
&= \\boldsymbol{\\pi r^2}
\\end{aligned}
"]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For kindness. Could you post using my second example?

Comment: What you did is correct ...

Answer (score 3):

MaTeX interprets TeX commands in inline math mode. Only those commands work that are allowed in inline math mode.

As @Nasser said, in this case use `aligned` instead of `align` (and make sure that the `amsmath` package is loaded—it is in the default `"BasePreamble"` option value).

This is discussed both [on the webpage you linked to](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/MaTeX), and the builtin documentation.  Please check the documentation (in particular the Possible Issues section) when encountering problems like this. It has answers to the most common questions.

[image]

Comment: How nice. The father of this package has found my question. I disclose your package a lot.